Albedo Map Texture Baking Issues: Color Inconsistencies and Missing Details from Procedural Textures
I am trying to bake an albedo map from the procedural texture applied on the model but facing problems. The problem is that the texture is not looking same as procedural texture colour is a bit off and it is missing details in some parts where it was visible in procedural one. I have tried making texture higher resolution, and check for uv stretching but both don't appear to be the reason for the difference in textures.
I should also mention that there are two materials applied on the object so I am not talking about those sudden regular transitions.






Download Google Drive Blend

I'm not absolutely sure I'm even seeing the differences between the two that you're talking about, but what minor differences I do see looks like a metallic map issue. If you transfer the albedo from one and apply only that one to the new model without also transferring the roughness and metallic values then you're gonna see some differences for sure.

If this doesn't fix your problem then I would ask that you share your Blender project file. Instructions for sharing.

@Jakemoyo the thing is that I am not transferring any texture maps between two different objects I am trying to bake out procedural texture map onto an image texture, now specifically albedo map and that is giving me problems it is missing out on details that are visible in procedural texture and it is missing out on details on some parts of the mesh not all of on which the material is applied . I will be sharing you the file thanks for help in advance

Here's the updated file sharing guide.

I would have used blend exchange but the file is heavy and I could not compress it further I have set access to anyone with link this time also the file I shared before was problematic for some reason. Here is the link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WNt4l7QAME6Ip02EYW19J-UCxRHDZE4d/view?usp=sharing

1.6GB filesize.... I doubt you really needed all that data to provide a sample file to show the issue. It's going to take a while just to download that, and some people simply won't even try to. It's explained in the guide.

Yes I get it you are making a valid point but I removed a thing or two to make file size even smaller, but it stared to show some weird purple colouring in the rendered view but not in the material preview I guess it was from deleting the hdri image as environment that I didn't understand at the time of uploading the full file so I will upload that smaller version again, yes you are right that I may not have needed that big of a file to illustrate the issue. I will see to it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FJCXNBHVmY_OLDg01RfynTdwgBzzt7H9/view?usp=sharing Here is the new link to smaller file

The really confusing thing is that the file you provide seen to not be set up to provide the exact same result you have in your question, at least not without changing things on our side. Render engine is set to Eevee which doesn't bake, other materials are baking different textures you didn't mention, and the result baking is nowhere near the same result as yours:

So we run the risk of not encountering the same troubles as you do just because we don't start precisely from your scenario.
Inspection
You have six different materials and six different UV maps, most without self-explanatory names, and inside your materials you have lots of image textures mixed together... That makes it quite hard to troubleshoot for you, and even more so for someone who doesn't know your file.
There is also one of your materials that seem to not be bakable. pbm2 gives out a lot of black spots, I suspect that it is because of how you mixed multiple Principled BSDF, it might not know what to do with it for some reason.
I'd advise making things as simple as you can, it will save you time and headaches. And that would be to have one final UV map with one material, one Principled BSDF and its image textures.
For the rest of the answer I will be using Blender 4.1 and the Textools addon:
Release TexTools 1.6.1 · franMarz/TexTools-Blender
It doesn't seem to have been updated for Blender 4.3 yet but it has some quite useful tools to manage UVs and baking.
I also recommend reading the whole answer before acting, since some decision-making at each step is needed depending on the end result you want and how you want it.
Fixing pbm 2
This material can be summarized by being multiple procedural and image textures combined at different places using masks. Instead of mixing shaders, let's mix the texture data instead, and feed that into one final Principled BSDF.
To help doing that, You can add reroute nodes to the noodles that feed each Principled BSDF and use its label to tell what is what. For properties that are different across all three Principled BSDF but not plugged to any input data, you can add value nodes to help too.

Then you can proceed to add one Principled BSDF, mix all the signals using Convert > Mix nodes from A to B and from AB to C:

With a bit of cleaning up, it looks like this:

And the baking works again.
UV map
You have six UV maps, with seemingly none of them exempt of UV overlap, so we can't use any of them as final.

Let's make a new UV map with a nice name: UVMap Final.
You could make your new UVs using the Smart UV Project, it's the fastest but it might not give the best result.
If you select all your mesh and unwrap as is, you will get this:

Most of it is fine, we can refine it a bit, I.E. that big T-shaped island could be cut with a seam at its junction. Select the edges, hit ⎈ CtrlE to open the Edge Specials menu and hit Mark Seams.
Another thing you have to pay attention is UVs overlaping each other. They are hard to spot, but Textools have a button to select the islands that have overlapping parts:

And then it takes a bit of close visual inspecting to see where it overlaps and how to fix it:

Notice the checker map, that is also a tool from Textools that is toggle-able and doesn't destroy your materials.
Setting up the baking
In each of your materials, add an image texture node, with an image named "bake", with 32 bits float and a big resolution. plug its vector input to a UV Map node with UVMap Final.
Keep only that bake image texture selected so that the baking happens only there.

Then you can bake. Using Textools there really speeds things up because you just have to pick the texture size, bake type and hit the bake button. It will automatically use the right bake type influences and even the right color management and depths of your texture depending on what you bake. It also have a basic super sampling Anti Aliasing (bakes at x times your desired resolution and scales it down to desired resolution).
The tricky part with your materials is that they have very fine details. The finely brushed metal aspect is hard to get in an image texture, here's what I get with a 8192 px² texture:

There are multiple ways to go about it. First one being to just go even higher in texture resolution. Or reading your UVs to make use of UDIM tiles, effectively giving yourself multiple set of textures of more or less high resolution instead of one ridiculously high resolution set of texture.
It would probably help to also modify UVs to try and align UVs as much as possible to the XY axes. Since your brushed metal is straight, it will require fewer pixels to represent if your UVs don't make them diagonal to the pixels.
If your model is meant to be viewed mostly from specific angles, it can also be interesting to scale up or down specific UV islands, to give more pixels to the most important parts. For example, if you know it won't be often seen from below, scale down the islands from the below parts of the mesh. Small bits that aren't clearly visible like junction parts or inside things can be scaled down too.
Another possible thing is also to consider scaling up the procedural textures to make them more accessible to your image textures. It can be done using Vector Math nodes set to Multiply and using a Value node shared across all Vector math nodes you add to uniformly scales all textures up in one material:

Here's what I get with scaling up your procedural textures and baking at 4096 px² with 2x AA:

It's not perfect, but already it makes the whole thing look decent at a human distance.
You can also do a little bit of all of that.
